# Keep Android debugger alive even after device restart

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent, boot

I am having trouble debugging some code in my DeviceBootReceiver (handles android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED intent). I want to debug this bit, but how does one keep the debugger alive, when the device reboots? Is there any hack that anyone has come across for this?

**What I want to do** :

1. Start debugging app via Android Studio
2. Power down the device
3. Power up the device
4. **Still** be able to get the debugger attached to my app when it starts to handle android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED intent

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open your device "developer options" settings;
2. Scroll down to "select debug app" and make sure your app is selected there;
3. Check the option "wait for debugger".

This will make sure that when your app is executed, for example when it receives a `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, the debugger gets attached first.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-broadcast the intent by yourself via adb shell:

`$ adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: This helped send the broadcast, but it killed the debugger! :(

Answer (score 0):

It takes about 30 seconds AFTER your device becomes available for interactions for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED to be broadcast.  You have enough time to start up your application and enter debug mode manually

You might want to print a timestamp to your logcat when the android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED intent is received so you have a better idea of when all this happens

Comment: This is eventually what I sort of end up doing, but @mr-t's answer helps time it better